# Issue with hotkeys, alt+s

Tags: javascript, hotkeys, alt-key

`Alt+s` is used for save in our application. When we press `alt+tab` then `alt` is captured and it switch to some different page and when we returned to our application then on pressing only `s` key its performing save functionality as alt key was already captured. Please suggest solution of this.
Already tried releasing alt key on press of `alt+tab` but on alt+tab,only alt is captured, tab not captured so don't know at what point to release alt key.

Answer (score 0):

Without specific code or working snippet I can suggest to work on the *blur* event of the browser window:

```
window.onblur = function() {
   // Reset events listeners
};

window.onfocus = function() {
   // Restore your events listeners
};
```

Comment: Used following code .it resolves the issue window.onfocus = function() { keys[18] =false; };            is it ok or any other suggestions??